# How can I click on span button which has no lisk with selenium webdriver Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

This is my HTML code:

```
<button class="_qv64e _gexxb _r9b8f _njrw0">Follow</button>
```

But, when I try to click on this this error is occurred:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element: span._qv64e _gexxb _r9b8f _njrw0

It is happened in any way that I used, for example in xpath, CSS selector, tag name and ... . This error has been occurred through this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span._qv64e _gexxb _r9b8f _njrw0").click()
```

Comment: why cant you use xpath?

Comment: It's not a `span`, but `button`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `css_selector` spaces has meaning. The selector you are using tell the driver to look for an element with `<_njrw0>` tag which has an ancestor with `<_r9b8f>` tag as so on. The button also has `<button>` tag, not `<span>` tag.

You need to use `.` in front of any class name and without spaces

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button._qv64e._gexxb._r9b8f._njrw0").click()
```

Comment: Can you what is the same problem, when I use xpath?

Comment: I used this code:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/header/section/div[1]/span/button""").click()

Comment: @hamedbaziyad Maybe the `xpath` is incorrect, I can't tell without seeing the complete html structure form the first element.